# socket.io control execution order with nested async and await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io, async-await

In my app, I have multiple users submitting data "at once" via a socket.event.
Because I need to know if every user has submitted their data successfully, I try to indentify the first and last entry.
For that, I call an async function on the event, which itself includes "await".

Basically, the function looks for a value in the database and then does something depending on whether it exists or not.

Because of that, I need the function block (with its awaits) to be fully executed before the next instance of the function is called.

However, what I found is that the as soon as I call await inside the function, the next instance of said function starts executing, which obviously messes everything up.

```
    socket.on("entries", async entries => {

        const firstEntry = await match.noEntries(mid);
        if (firstEntry) {
            //do sth
        }

        await match.submitEntries(mid, socket.pid, entries);        

    });

//FUNCTION

noEntries: async (mid) => {
    const entries = await database.query("...");
    return (entries.length == 0);
}
```

Is there any way I can prevent the next instance of the function to be executed before it's predecessor has finished?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: let me ask to see if I got your question. So you basically want to execute every callback from your "entries" even synchronously between them (like one after another), although each callback are asynchronous by itself?

Comment: yes, that's on point